# Catching SIGCHLD with sigaction

Tags: c, signals, fork

I am reading an article about signal and there was this part of the code which I am not sure what it is doing. Could somebody explain it for me? This article is about creating TCP un-blocked server.

```
struct sigaction sigchldAction;
sigchldAction.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigchldAction.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset(&sigchldAction.sa_mask);
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchldAction, NULL) == -1) callError("sigaction()");
```

Comment: It sounds like you already know what the code does. What's the question?

Comment: I am not sure why there is SIG_IGn in sa_handler.

Comment: @user3463055 That's a define for a special address value (like `NULL` but different (`0x1` on my system)). The kernel will notice it and interpret it it as a command to ignore the signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Linux manual page for `sigaction`:

> POSIX.1-1990 disallowed setting the  action  for  SIGCHLD  to 
>   SIG_IGN.    POSIX.1-2001  allows  this possibility, so that ignoring
>   SIGCHLD can be    used to prevent the creation of zombies (see 
>   wait(2)).

That is, explicitly ignoring `SIGCHLD` using `SIG_IGN` has the effect of causing the OS to automatically destroy child processes upon termination, so that you don't have to `wait*` for them. This is often what you want, although sometimes it isn't, because it also *prevents* the parent process from using `wait*` to determine the child's exit status.

Comment: So with this part of the code, I will destroy child processes? I thought that to destroy child process I have to use wait().

Comment: @user3463055 like I said, it causes the OS to automatically destroy child processes so the parent process doesn't need to call `wait*`. Was my answer not clear enough?